# What is the correct value of raster effect resolution parameter in Adobe Illustrator for saving PNG used in an iPad application

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mobile

I have a graphic prepared in Adobe Illustrator that I need to export to a PNG file used in an iPad application. The default value of Raster Effect resolution parameter is 72 ppi, on the other hand iPad spec says that its screen has 132 ppi.

Shall I change resolution from 72 ppi to 132 ppi before exporting PNG file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GENERALLY for electronic use, what matters is the pixel dimensions of the item, and inches don't really exist. So while the iPad's rendering libraries *might* work off of inches instead of pixels (which I doubt), my recommendation is to select the setting which results in a PNG that meets the pixel dimension specification for your application.

If you export a PNG @ 132 ppi, do you end up with a PNG that is too large for your requirements when measured in pixels?

Comment: Correct. DPI settings in illustrator are moot when it comes to creating screen graphics.